# How to recover lost data through transfer?

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, file-transfer, micro-sd-card

I have made a terrible mistake when transferring photos from a microSD card to an external HDD.

I connect the microSD card and the external HDD to my iPad. I could see all the photos from SD card. I selected all of them and wanted to copy to the external HDD, but I couldn't find a "copy" button, so I clicked the "move" button (Very wrong! I regret so much).

Unfortunately, there are too many files (more than 4 000), and my iPad ran out of battery, so the MOVE process was interrupted. After that, all the files (about 2 000) in the external HDD though show their names, their sizes are 0 bite. Those files in microSD card, too, show only their names and their sizes are all 0 bite.

What can I do?

Comment: You might get lucky using photorec or recuva - these scan the underlying disk looking for file signatures and can recover image files if they are not fragmented (but sans filename)

Comment: What device was the microSD used in, so what device was used to record/shoot the files?

Comment: The micro SD card was used in a Samsung mobile phone.

Comment: Yes PhotoRe is amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the µSD card in USB adapter, such as [this for US$5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B9QZ4W4Y).
2. [Clone the card *verbatim*](https://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/clone-resource/top-6-sd-card-cloning-software.html), so that the copy includes *everything* on the card.
3. On a PC, use standard data recovery tools, such as Recuva, PhotoRec or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/recuva/) on the **copy** of the flash drive.

If you immediately took the card out, after realizing the issue, the likelihood of full recovery is very good. If it's been used since the failed move, chances are reduced.

Why not use the original? Sometimes recovery can damage data. If the clone is damaged, make another copy and try a different tool.

Comment: Thank you DrMoishe so much! I like PhotoRe a lot and it’s fantastic and at the same time free open source!!! Your solution is the best. But I was so lucky today to find that all photos are back when I had my iPad recharged and connected with the external hard drive and the micro as card. Something that Apple did well. Thanks to all who commented. What a relief and also feel great that I will know how to deal such things in thie future. 